# how can i toggle changes in background color using only the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, togglebutton

I'm trying to make this toggle accessible and I've succeeded in getting the arrow keys to toggle the switch but I'm unable to change the background color of the h1 which defeats the purpose of the accessible toggle. what am I doing wrong here? i tried using the keydwon listener and I'm getting the inputs from the arrow keys but not receiving the accurate data attribute from the inputs.

my code:-
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Three Pos</h2>
    <div class="container">
        
        <input data-type="first" type="radio" id="first" name="toggle_option2">
        <input data-type="second" type="radio" id="second" name="toggle_option2" checked>
        <input data-type="third" type="radio" id="third" name="toggle_option2">
        
        <label data-radio="first" for="first" class="radio one"><p>Lions</p></label>
        <label data-radio="second" for="second" class="radio bottom two"><p>Tigers</p></label>
        <label data-radio="third" for="third" class="radio three"><p>Bears</p></label>
        <div class="bg"></div>

    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*,
*::after,
*::before{
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}


:root{
    --bg-one: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
    --bg-two: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
    --bg-three: hsl(39, 100%, 50%);
}

[color-scheme='first']{
    --bg: var(--bg-one);
}

[color-scheme='second']{
    --bg: var(--bg-two);
}

[color-scheme='third']{
    --bg: var(--bg-three);
}




body{
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    place-content: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
    color: white;
}

h2{
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--bg);
}



.bg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    top: -5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 350ms ease,
                left 250ms ease ;
    
}


.container input[type=radio]:checked ~ .bg {
    background-color: green;
}

.container input[type=radio]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .bg {
    background-color: red;
    left: -1px;
}

.container input[type=radio]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .bg {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 31px;
}

.container input[type=radio]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .bg {
    background-color: orange;
    left: 60px;
}
```

JS

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root')
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.radio')
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input [type="radio"]')

let theme = 'second';
root.setAttribute('color-scheme', `${theme}`)

const loadTheme = theme => {
    root.setAttribute('color-scheme', `${theme}`)
}

toggle.forEach(radio =>{ 
    radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let theme = radio.getAttribute('data-radio')
        loadTheme(theme)
    })
})


document.addEventListener('keydown', e =>{
    console.log(e)
    input.forEach(radio =>{ 
        let theme = radio.getAttribute('data-type')
        loadTheme(theme)
    })
})
```

edit:- removed unnecessary CSS cuz I couldn't post the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. in case anyone else is facing the same issue here is the solution.

first, remove this code from app.js :-

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e =>{
    console.log(e)
    input.forEach(radio =>{ 
        let theme = radio.getAttribute('data-type')
        loadTheme(theme)
    })
})
```

and now add this code instead in app.js :-

```
input.forEach(button => {
    //console.log(button.checked)
    button.addEventListener('change', e=>{
        let radio = e.target;
        theme = button.getAttribute('data-type');
        loadTheme(theme)
    })
    
})
```

the issue was that by using the keydown event listener I was able to get the data-type but it was of the PREVIOUS state. (for ex. if I had clicked from tigers to bears id be getting the data type of tigers and not bdata type of bears which is where our toggle is currently switched to. )

instead using change eventlistener we can get the CURRENT data type that our toggle is locked in.